# unable to retrieve logged in user's id in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm finding it difficult retrieving the logged in user's id (from the records table in mysql database). I tried the function below to retrieve it, but doesn't work.

```
<?php
    $password = md5($password);
    $sql = "select * from users where username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($count==1 && $row['password'] == $password){
         $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
         header('location: loggedin.php');
    }else{
         $errorMsg = 'Invalid Username or Password';
    }
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
 $user_id = userid(id,username);



function userid(id,username)
{
    $sql = "select id from users where username =  $_SESSION['username']"
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the following:

- The way you call your function, you have to put declared variables as arguments
- You don't have nothing to `return` from your function
- You forgot semi-colon (`;`) in declaring your `$sql` variable

You can replace the `id` argument with your database connection instead:

```
function userid($dbcon, $username)
{
    $stmt = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    return $id;
}
```

Then, call the function:

```
/** HOPE YOU DECLARED SOMEWHERE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION PRIOR TO YOUR FUNCTION CALL **/
$username = $_SESSION['username']; /** JUST REPLACE THIS WITH ANY DATA YOU WANT **/

$user_id = userid($dbcon, $username);
```

What bothers me is, why do you store the `username` of the user in a session variable instead of the `id`? What if the user changes his/her username while logged-in?

Comment: hello wayne..pertaining to the function, what will be the value of username in the query above? like should I say username = $username; since that's what is passed from db? And also...in the parameters of the function, I dont quite understand the $dbcon. My dbcon is in a separate php file that is attached to the 'loggedin.php'.(that's what connects to mysql db) How can I make it a variable like you have there? Gracias.

Comment: As long as you declare/include your database connection variable (`$dbcon`) before calling your `userid()` function, that would suffice. You can put your session variable to your `$username` variable. Also, please see my concerns in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: OK... Thanks a lot.